# How to test the increase is notable

Tags: statistical-significance

Here is my case.

There are like 1000 monitoring sites which measure CO2 concentration continuously.

I define two period: 1950 - 1970; 1971 - 1991 and compute the average concentration of these period.

Since the variation of all sites are different (some increase, some decrease)?

How to ensure the increase of CO2 concentration is notable in statistic method?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a rank test such as Wilcoxon signed-rank test?

There is an example http://www.biostathandbook.com/wilcoxonsignedrank.html. I think it's similar to your scenario:

- **Clones** in your example would be sites
- **Metal** content in your example would be average CO2 concentration
- **August** in your example would be 1950-1970
- **November** in your example would be 1971-1991

If the average CO2 do increase over the period, your pairs should not follow a symmetric distribution. You can use the test to reject the null hypothesis that the median difference between pairs of observations is zero.